# Sul suffisso -aggine

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Qual'è l'origine del suffisso ***-aggine*** che generalmente da una connotazione negativa alle parole a cui viene aggiunto? Ad esempio: stupidaggine, dabbenaggine, sfacciataggine e bambinaggine.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Secondo [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aggine/) deriva dal suffiso latino "-ago, -agĭnis":

> [...] L’antico valore del suffisso lat., mediante il quale si formavano nomi di vegetali, si conserva in borraggine, fusaggine, piantaggine e pochi altri.

Non sono date ulteriori informazioni purtroppo, comunque dovrebbe essere sufficiente a spiegarne l'origine: il suffisso originale veniva utilizzato come desinenza per formare nomi di vegetali, in alcuni dei quali in Italiano tra l'altro rimane (nella forma "-aggine").

Comment: È curioso come un suffisso usato per i vegetali in italiano abbia assunto una connotazione negativa,

Comment: @Josh61 Si, neanch'io vedo la correlazione. L'unica cosa sarebbe che (secondo Wikipedia) la borraggine a un certo punto della vita è tossica, e la fusaggine è proprio velenosa; però lo stesso non vale per la piantaggine